# Avro schema with map of obejct?

Tags: go, maps, avro

```golang
type Job struct {
   Name string
   MaskSchema map[string]MaskInfo
}


type MaskInfo struct {
  Masked bool
  SortCol bool
}
```

How to represent Job as avro schema?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [goavro](https://github.com/linkedin/goavro):

```
type Job struct {
   Name string
   MaskSchema map[string]MaskInfo
}


type MaskInfo struct {
  Masked bool
  SortCol bool
}

newJob := Job{
    // fill the struct
}

textual, err = codec.TextualFromNative(nil, newJob)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

fmt.Println(string(textual))
```

Note: I didn't test it, but it should work.

see documentation: https://github.com/linkedin/goavro

Comment: I needed a avro schema spec for the above golang struct ...was finding difficulty in representing an avro spec for the go object

Comment: Also the job spec will change everytime that map is a database columns I don't know what values will come

Comment: @AlokKumarSingh  maybe you can use `map[string]interface{}` instead of struct

Comment: How to write the avsc file for the above struct? How to represent the map of string interface in avro schema

Comment: @AlokKumarSingh see this https://github.com/linkedin/goavro/blob/bca45ff5413acd0447a8b5ca255a2013be5403f5/codec.go#L434-L465

Comment: Thanks but very confusing, could you please edit ur answer with a avro schema for the struct if possible... It could help me understand better